# Otimizar consulta, reduzindo subqueries (+ de 1 alias por subquery, é possível?)

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de reduzir o número de consultas na minha query.
Como os dados são distribuidos em diferentes tabelas, vou coletando as informações necessárias através de comparações com seus IDs.

Hoje minha consulta é esta. **Ela é funcional**, porém, deve ser bem custosa à performance:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT trtId FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as trtIdOrigem, 
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdOrigem) as trtTituloOrigem, 
    (SELECT treNome FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treNomeOrigem, 
    (SELECT treICAO FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treICAOOrigem, 
    (SELECT treIATA FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treIATAOrigem, 
    (SELECT trtId FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as trtIdDestino, 
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdDestino) as trtTituloDestino, 
    (SELECT treNome FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treNomeDestino, 
    (SELECT treICAO FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treICAODestino, 
    (SELECT treIATA FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treIATADestino,
    (SELECT cidNome FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treEnderecoCidadeOrigem,
    (SELECT cidAlias FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treAliasCidadeOrigem,
    (SELECT estUF FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cido.estId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treEnderecoEstadoOrigem,
    (SELECT cidNome FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treEnderecoCidadeDestino,
    (SELECT cidAlias FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treAliasCidadeDestino,
    (SELECT estUF FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cidd.estId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treEnderecoEstadoDestino

FROM 
    sistema_voo_operadora vop 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_operadora ope ON vop.opeId = ope.opeId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_voo voo ON vop.vooId = voo.vooId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_voo tiv ON voo.tivId = tiv.tivId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_aeronave aer ON vop.aerId = aer.aerId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_aeronave tia ON aer.tiaId = tia.tiaId

WHERE 
    tiv.tivId = 2 
    AND vooAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vooExcluido = 'N' 
    AND opeAtivo = 'S' 
    AND opeExcluido = 'N' 
    AND vopAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vopExcluido = 'N' 

ORDER BY 
    RAND() 

LIMIT 
    0,4;
```

Gostaria de, ao menos, as subqueries iniciais fossem agrupadas de alguma maneira. Tentei o seguinte, mas sem sucesso (retornou Syntax Error):

**Tentativa 01:**

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT trtId, treNome, treICAO, treIATA FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as trtIdOrigem, treNomeOrigem, treICAOOrigem, treIATAOrigem 
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdOrigem) as trtTituloOrigem, 
    (SELECT trtId, treNome, treICAO, treIATA FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as trtIdDestino, treNomeDestino, treICAODestino, treIATADestino
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdDestino) as trtTituloDestino, 
    (SELECT cidNome FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treEnderecoCidadeOrigem,
    (SELECT cidAlias FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treAliasCidadeOrigem,
    (SELECT estUF FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cido.estId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId) as treEnderecoEstadoOrigem,
    (SELECT cidNome FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treEnderecoCidadeDestino,
    (SELECT cidAlias FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treAliasCidadeDestino,
    (SELECT estUF FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cidd.estId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId) as treEnderecoEstadoDestino

FROM 
    sistema_voo_operadora vop 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_operadora ope ON vop.opeId = ope.opeId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_voo voo ON vop.vooId = voo.vooId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_voo tiv ON voo.tivId = tiv.tivId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_aeronave aer ON vop.aerId = aer.aerId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_aeronave tia ON aer.tiaId = tia.tiaId

WHERE 
    tiv.tivId = 2 
    AND vooAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vooExcluido = 'N' 
    AND opeAtivo = 'S' 
    AND opeExcluido = 'N' 
    AND vopAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vopExcluido = 'N' 

ORDER BY 
    RAND() 

LIMIT 
    0,4;
```

**Tentativa 02:**

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT trtId as trtIdOrigem as treNomeOrigem, treNome as treNomeOrigem, treICAO as treICAOOrigem, treIATA as treIATAOrigem FROM sistema_trecho treo WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId),
    (SELECT trtId as trtIdDestino, treNome as treNomeDestino, treICAO as treICAODestino, treIATA as treIATADestino FROM sistema_trecho tred WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId),
    (SELECT cidNome as treEnderecoCidadeOrigem, cidAlias as treAliasCidadeOrigem, estUF as treEnderecoEstadoOrigem FROM sistema_trecho treo LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cido ON cido.cidId = treo.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cido.estId WHERE treo.treId = voo.vooOrigemId),
    (SELECT cidNome as treEnderecoCidadeDestino, cidAlias as treAliasCidadeDestino, estUF as treEnderecoEstadoDestino FROM sistema_trecho tred LEFT JOIN sistema_cidade cidd ON cidd.cidId = tred.cidId LEFT JOIN sistema_estado est ON est.estId = cidd.estId WHERE tred.treId = voo.vooDestinoId),
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdOrigem) as trtTituloOrigem, 
    (SELECT trtTitulo FROM sistema_trecho_tipo trt WHERE trt.trtId = trtIdDestino) as trtTituloDestino

FROM 
    sistema_voo_operadora vop 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_operadora ope ON vop.opeId = ope.opeId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_voo voo ON vop.vooId = voo.vooId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_voo tiv ON voo.tivId = tiv.tivId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_aeronave aer ON vop.aerId = aer.aerId 
    LEFT JOIN sistema_tipo_aeronave tia ON aer.tiaId = tia.tiaId

WHERE 
    tiv.tivId = 2 
    AND vooAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vooExcluido = 'N' 
    AND opeAtivo = 'S' 
    AND opeExcluido = 'N' 
    AND vopAtivo = 'S' 
    AND vopExcluido = 'N' 

ORDER BY 
    RAND() 

LIMIT 
    0,4;
```

**Resumindo a brincadeira:**

Preciso trazer 4 registros da tabela sistema_voo_operadora (vop)

Dentro desta, preciso trazer os dados do voo (voo), que estão em sistema_voo (voo.vooId = vop.vooId)

Dentro da tabela voo, guardo o ID do trecho de partida e o ID do trecho de destino. Os dados originais estão em sistema_trecho (treo para origem, e tred para destino). Como preciso da cidade, estado e slug de cada trecho ainda nesta consulta, minha saída foram fazer subqueries.

Os left joins são necessários para trazer mais infos externas, como informações da operadora, do tipo do voo, da aeronave utilizada e o tipo da aeronave.

O que eu puder otimizar nesta query, me salvaria alguns cabelos.

Ideias?